# tf.keras(tf2) problem: can't run custom gradient layers, OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError. May caused by tf.Keras API

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, keras-layer, tf.keras, generative-adversarial-network

I've arranged my code on [github](https://github.com/xiqxin1/dann-tf.keras-test)(with avaiable dataset).

The problem is that I want to implement an unsupervised domain adversarial training network (DANN) [(see paper)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.07818) using tf2.keras code, while most of the answers are tf1 or pure [keras](https://github.com/michetonu/DA-RNN_manoeuver_anticipation/blob/93706abc3a45d99e027bc8277b7c20a61bdf11c8/da_rnn/DA_RNN_anticipation.py#L314) versions, they didn't directly consider the change between tf1 and tf2, and simply disabled eager execution.

When I try to add a custom gradient_reversal layer at the beginning of my domain_classifier like this:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def reverse_gradient(X, hp_lambda):
    """Flips the sign of the incoming gradient during training."""
    try:
        reverse_gradient.num_calls += 1
    except AttributeError:
        reverse_gradient.num_calls = 1

    grad_name = "GradientReversal%d" % reverse_gradient.num_calls

    @ops.RegisterGradient(grad_name)
    def _flip_gradients(grad):
        return [tf.negative(grad) * hp_lambda]

    # g = K.get_session().graph
    with tf.Graph().as_default() as g:
        with g.gradient_override_map({'Identity': grad_name}):
            y = tf.identity(X)
    return y

from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer # I use base_layer, and most errors are coming from here.
class GradientReversal(Layer):
    """Layer that flips the sign of gradient during training."""

    def __init__(self, hp_lambda, **kwargs):
        super(GradientReversal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.hp_lambda = hp_lambda

    # @staticmethod
    def get_output_shape_for(input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def build(self, input_shape):
        # self.trainable_weights = []
        return

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        return reverse_gradient(x, self.hp_lambda)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def get_config(self):
        config = {}
        base_config = super(GradientReversal, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

There are a lot of errors ocurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1117, in _functional_construction_call
outputs = call_fn(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 258, in wrapper
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

D:/Skill-worker-research/Python code and example data/SupplementarySoftware_DeepHL_python/DeepHL_python/danntest/main.py:117 call  *
    return reverse_gradient(x, self.hp_lambda)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\custom_gradient.py:264 __call__  **
    return self._d(self._f, a, k)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\custom_gradient.py:220 decorated
    return _graph_mode_decorator(wrapped, args, kwargs)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\custom_gradient.py:325 _graph_mode_decorator
    result, grad_fn = f(*args)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:503 __iter__
    self._disallow_iteration()
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:499 _disallow_iteration
    self._disallow_in_graph_mode("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:479 _disallow_in_graph_mode
    " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1124, in _functional_construction_call
'\n"""')
TypeError: You are attempting to use Python control flow in a layer that was not declared to be dynamic. Pass `dynamic=True` to the class constructor.
Encountered error:
"""
in user code:

D:/Skill-worker-research/Python code and example data/SupplementarySoftware_DeepHL_python/DeepHL_python/danntest/main.py:117 call  *
    return reverse_gradient(x, self.hp_lambda)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\custom_gradient.py:264 __call__  **
    return self._d(self._f, a, k)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\custom_gradient.py:220 decorated
    return _graph_mode_decorator(wrapped, args, kwargs)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\custom_gradient.py:325 _graph_mode_decorator
    result, grad_fn = f(*args)
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:503 __iter__
    self._disallow_iteration()
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:499 _disallow_iteration
    self._disallow_in_graph_mode("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
D:\Users\xiqxi\Anaconda3\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:479 _disallow_in_graph_mode
    " this function with @tf.function.".format(task))

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use 
Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

"""

Process finished with exit code -1
```

I noticed that @tf.custom_gradient is tf2 code, but tf2 no longer uses tf.Graph() to generate static graph when building network structure, so I try this code anyway:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def GradientReversalOperator(x):
    def grad(dy):
        return -1 * dy
    return x, grad
```

But another bug raised. I guess this is because class GradientReversal inherites tf.keras.base_layer which contains tf1's gramma. I cannot fix such problem even I tried so many ways.

I uploaded my code and put forward this question. Hopefully, there are someone who can help me fix the problem and tell me how the tf.keras.base_layer works as well as why it doesn't available on my code.

I'll be very appretiate if you can give me any advices.

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Now, I fixed the problem.

Remove:

from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer

To

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer

But another error ocurrs:

```
InternalError: Recorded operation 'GradientReversalOperator' returned too few gradients. Expected 3 but received 2
```